# looking for a sql query word

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table struct in sql server 2008:

```
+--------+-----+---------------------+
|  user  | val |        time         |
+--------+-----+---------------------+
|     kk |  21 | 2011-12-12 12:23:00 |
|     dd |  33 | 2011-12-12 12:23:00 |
|     kk |  22 | 2011-12-12 12:23:30 |
|     dd |  33 | 2011-12-12 12:23:30 |
+--------+-----+---------------------+
```

This record in the table are updated by other application every 30 seconds.

Now,I want to query the latest records of all the user in the table.

Any way to implement it using just one sql query?

Comment: We need to know more about what those columns are and what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list the user and the latest time entry

```
select user,max(time)
from table
group by user
```

If you need the associated data, try this

```
select a.* 
from table a
join ( select user,max(time) as TheLatest
       from table
       group by user ) xx
on a.time=xx.theLatest and xx.user=a.user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT

            USER
            ,Val
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User,Time ORDER BY Time DESC) AS SlNo
    FROM    myTable
) result
WHERE       SlNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
DECLARE @tbl table(ID INT,dtm datetime)

    insert into @tbl 
    values  (1,'2011-09-14 00:59:00'),
            (2,'2011-09-15'),
            (2,'2011-09-15 05:10:00'),
            (5,'2011-09-16 05:10:00'),
            (8,'2011-10-29 05:10:00'),
            (5,'2011-10-29'),
            (6,'2011-10-30')


    select MAX(dtm),ID from @tbl 
       GROUP BY  ID
```